# How to swap adapters for Ember-parse-adaptor to default when offline

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

How can I swap my adapters for an environment? I want to just use a rest adaptor  when not having internet but with net I want use the ember parse adaptor.

when you use the parse adaptor it changes how the default app works via:

```
export default function( container, app ) {
  Adapter.reopen({
    applicationId : app.get( 'applicationId' ),
    restApiId     : app.get( 'restApiId' )
  });

  container.register( 'adapter:-parse', Adapter );
  container.register( 'serializer:-parse', Serializer );
  container.register( 'transform:parse-date', DateTransform );
  container.register( 'transform:parse-file', FileTransform );
  container.register( 'transform:parse-geo-point', GeopointTransform );
  container.register( 'model:parse-user', ParseUser );
}
```

Comment: are you using ember-cli?

Comment: @KoriJohnRoys yes I am

Answer (score 1):

With ember-cli it shouldn't be too rough. I'm not 100% sure about how parse-adapter sets the application adapter for you, but give this a try. Just sub out `app-name` for whatever your application's name is, or use a relative path.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import ENV from 'app-name/config/environment';
import ParseAdapter from 'ember-parse-adapter/adapters/application';

var adapter;

if (ENV.environment === 'development') {
  adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend();
} else {
  adapter = ParseAdapter.extend();
});
}

export default adapter;
```

Comment: the parse adaptor just extends the rest one:
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({

Comment: it is extended in addon/adaptors/application